# Работа с массивом map

Tags: c++

Как использовать, например вывести элементы массива map. У меня есть проект, маааленький язык программирования, для реализации переменных использовал массив map и отдельный класс, но я новичёк и не умею пользоваться map, подскажите, пожалуйста, как использовать а моём случае!

Compiler.cpp:

```
#include "Compiler.h"

Compiler::Compiler() //конструктор
{

}

Compiler::~Compiler() //деструктор
{

}

int Compiler::cleaner() //чистка файла
{
system("clear");
ofstream cl("file.txt");
if(cl.is_open()) //если удалось открыть файл, чистим его и выходим из программы
{
    cl.clear();
    cout << "Successful cleaning!\n";
    cl.close();
    return 0;
}
else if(!cl.is_open()) //если не удалось открыть файл, возвращаем код ошибки (4)
{
    cout << "\aError of cleaning! (Error code 4)";
    return 4;
}
}

int Compiler::getFileCode() //получение кода из файла
{
ifstream in;
in.open(filename.c_str());
if(in.is_open()) //если удалось открыть файл, получаем из него строку и кладём в вектор до тех пор, пока не кончится файл
{
    while(getline(in, line))
    {
        code.push_back(line);
    }
    in.close();
}
else if(!in.is_open()) //если не удалось открыть файл, возвращаем код ошибки (1)
{
    cout << "\aError of read! (Error code 1)";
    return 1;
}
}

int Compiler::getKeyboardCode() //получение кода с клавиатуры
{
cout << "Enter code:\n";
cin.ignore();
do
{
    getline(cin, line); //ввод кода с клавиатуры
    code.push_back(line);

    ofstream out(filename.c_str(), ofstream::out|ofstream::app);
    if(out.is_open()) //если удалось открыть файл, чистим файл и записываем туда введённый с клавиатуры код
    {
        out.clear();
        out << line << endl;
        out.close();
    }
    else if(!out.is_open()) //если не удалось открыть файл, возвращаем код ошибки (2)
    {
        cout << "\aError of writing! (Error code 2)";
        return 2;
    }
}
while(line != "END"); //пока строка, введённая с клавиатуры не будет равна оператору END
}

void Compiler::getCode() //получение кода
{
if(gettingOfCode == "file") //получение кода из файла
{
    Compiler::getFileCode();
}
else if(gettingOfCode == "keyboard") //получение кода с клавиатуры
{
    Compiler::getKeyboardCode();
}
}

int Compiler::compile() //компилятор
{
Compiler::getCode(); //получаем код

system("clear"); //чистим экран

if(code.size() == 0) //если размер вектора равен нулю (файл пуст), сообщаем об этом и выходим из программы
{
    cout << "\aFile is empty!\n";
    return 0;
}
else if(code.size() > 0) //если размер вектора больше нуля (в файле есть код), переводим код на C++
{
    //служебная информация
    cout << "Successful compiling!\n" << "File: " << filename <<"\nLines in code: " << code.size()-1 << "\nOutput:" << endl;

    for(int i(0); i <= code.size(); i++)
    {
        //комментарий (//)
        if(strstr(code[i].c_str(), comment.c_str()))
        {
            code[i].clear();
        }
        //работа спеременными
        if(strstr(code[i].c_str(), integer.c_str())) //INTEGER
        {
            Variables int_buf;
            int_buf.setType(integer);
            varName = code[i].substr(0, code[i].find('='));
            stringstream converter(code[i].substr(code[i].find('=')+2));
            int buf;
            converter >> buf;
            int_buf.setInteger(buf);
            vars.insert(pair<string, Variables> (varName, int_buf));
            cout << varName;
        }
        if(strstr(code[i].c_str(), str.c_str())) //LINE
        {
            Variables line_buf;
            line_buf.setType(str);
            varName = code[i].substr(0, code[i].find('='));
            line_buf.setString(code[i].substr(code[i].find('=')+2));
            vars.insert(pair<string, Variables> (varName, line_buf));
            cout << line_buf.getString();
        }
        if(strstr(code[i].c_str(), boolean.c_str())) //BOOL
        {
            Variables bool_buf;
            bool_buf.setType(boolean);
            varName = code[i].substr(0, code[i].find('='));
            stringstream converter(code[i].substr(code[i].find('=')+2));
            int buf;
            converter >> buf;
            bool buf1 = buf;
            bool_buf.setBool(buf);
            vars.insert(pair<string, Variables> (varName, bool_buf));
            cout << bool_buf.getBool();
        }
        //описание операторов
        if(strstr(code[i].c_str(), operator1.c_str())) //вывод (PRINT)
        {
            cout << code[i].substr(6);
        }
        if(strstr(code[i].c_str(), operator2.c_str())) //ввод (INPUT)
        {

        }
        if(strstr(code[i].c_str(), operator3.c_str())) //звуковой сигнал (ALERT)
        {
            cout << "\a";
        }
        if(strstr(code[i].c_str(), operator4.c_str())) //выход (END)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if(strstr(code[i].c_str(), operator5.c_str())) //перенос строки (EL)
        {
            cout << "\n";
        }
        if(strstr(code[i].c_str(), operator6.c_str())) //цикл (CYCLE)
        {
            do
            {

            }
            while(strstr(code[i].c_str(), operator7.c_str()));
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Compiler.h:

```
#ifndef COMPILER_H
#define COMPILER_H

#include "Variables.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Compiler
{
public:
int compile(); //компилятор
int cleaner(); //чистка файла
string gettingOfCode = ""; //способ получения кода
string filename = ""; //имя файла

Compiler(); //конструктор
virtual ~Compiler(); //деструктор
private:
//операторы
string operator1 = "PRINT";
string operator2 = "INPUT";
string operator3 = "ALERT";
string operator4 = "END";
string operator5 = "EL";
string operator6 = "CYCLE";
string operator7 = "EC";
string operator8 = "=";
//работа с переменными
string integer = "INTEGER";
string str = "LINE";
string boolean = "BOOL";
map<string, Variables> vars;
string varName;
//
string comment = "//";
//получение кода
string line;
vector<string>code;
void getCode();
int getFileCode();
int getKeyboardCode();
};

#endif // COMPILER_H
```

Variables.cpp:

```
#include "Variables.h"
#include "Compiler.h"

Variables::Variables()
{
//ctor
}

Variables::~Variables()
{
//dtor
}

void Variables::setType(string type)
{
varType = type;
}

string Variables::getType()
{
return varType;
}

void Variables::setInteger(int i)
{
integerVal = i;
}

int Variables::getInteger()
{
return integerVal;
}

void Variables::setString(string l)
{
lineVal = l;
}

string Variables::getString()
{
return lineVal;
}

void Variables::setBool(bool b)
{
boolVal = b;
}

bool Variables::getBool()
{
return boolVal;
}
```

Variables.h:

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H
#define VARIABLES_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Variables
{
public:
void setType(string type);
string getType();
void setInteger(int);
int getInteger();
void setString(string);
string getString();
void setBool(bool);
bool getBool();
Variables();
virtual ~Variables();
protected:
private:
string varType;
int integerVal;
string lineVal;
bool boolVal;

};

#endif // VARIABLES_H
```

Comment: Зачем вы привели здесь столько кода? Какая у вас проблема с массивом из map? Покажите только релевантный код, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: нужно получить доступ к паре из мапа vars и, например, вывести

Comment: @VladfromMoscow нужно получить доступ к паре из мапа vars и, например, вывести

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать, используя различные подходы к организации прохода по массиву и соответственно по его элементам, комбинируя их между собой.

Вот демонстрационная программа, которая показывает несколько подходов к решению задачи в действии

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::pair<std::string, std::string>> m[2] =
    {        
        {
            { 1, { "Peter", "Falcone" } },
            { 2, { "Luisa", "Falcone" } }
        },

        {
            { 3, { "John", "Tomson" } }, 
            { 4, { "Ann", "Tomson" } }
        }            
    };    


    for ( const auto & family : m )
    {
        for ( const auto &name : family )
        {
            std::cout << name.first << ": " << name.second.first << ", " 
                      << name.second.second << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( m ) / sizeof( *m ); i++ )
    {
        for ( auto it = m[i].begin(); it != m[i].end(); ++it )
        {            
            std::cout << it->first << ": " << it->second.first << ", " 
                      << it->second.second << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод на консоль будет следующим:

```
1: Peter, Falcone
2: Luisa, Falcone

3: John, Tomson
4: Ann, Tomson


1: Peter, Falcone
2: Luisa, Falcone

3: John, Tomson
4: Ann, Tomson
```

Если по какой-то причине ваш компилятор не поддерживает инициализацию `std::map` с помощью списка инициализации, то в демонстрационной программе вы можете заменить объявление массива на следующий код:

```
std::map<int, std::pair<std::string, std::string>> m[2];

m[0][1] = std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Peter", "Falcone" );
m[0][2] = std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Luisa", "Falcone" );
m[1][3] = std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "John", "Tomson" );
m[1][4] = std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Ann", "Tomson" );
```